# mu4e bookmarks: how to hide messages for folders like Trash and Spam?

Tags: mu4e

I am trying `mu4u` for Gmail and an Exchange account.

```
;;; Mail directory shortcuts
  (setq mu4e-maildir-shortcuts
        '(("/Gmail/INBOX" . ?g)
          ("/Exchange/INBOX" . ?a)))

;;; Bookmarks
  (setq mu4e-bookmarks
        `(("flag:unread AND NOT flag:trashed AND NOT (maildir:/[Gmail].Trash OR maildir:/Trash)" "Unread messages" ?u)
          ("date:today..now" "Today's messages" ?t)
          ("date:7d..now" "Last 7 days" ?w)
          ("mime:image/*" "Messages with images" ?p)
          (,(mapconcat 'identity
                       (mapcar
                        (lambda (maildir)
                          (concat "maildir:" (car maildir)))
                        mu4e-maildir-shortcuts) " OR ")
           "All inboxes" ?i)))

  )
```

On `mu4e` main view, hitting `bu` brings me unread email from all over places including Trash folders.

How do I change it so that I don't see messages that are trashed in Trash folders or marked spam?

Answer (score 10):

You can skip specific maildir from indexing for search, using .noindex file.

from mu-index(1):

> If  there is a file called .noindex in a directory, the contents of that directory and all of its subdirectories
>   will be ignored. This can be useful to exclude certain directories from the indexing process, for example direc‐
>   tories with spam-messages.

ex. $ touch ~/Maildir/Gmail/[Gmail].Trash/.noindex && mu index

Comment: Then you can't even see them when you jump to their maildirs in mu4e. So you lose the ability to check Spam for wrongly filed emails.

Answer (score 1):

If your query is not returning the results you expect, try expanding it out. Sometimes there are [bugs](https://github.com/djcb/mu/issues/1140) with features like parentheses. That is, instead of:

`flag:unread AND NOT (maildir:/Trash OR maildir:/[Gmail].Trash)`

try:

`flag:unread AND NOT maildir:/Trash AND NOT maildir:/[Gmail].Trash`

Also note that if you are trying these at the command line with `mu-find`, you should escape or quote the parts with special characters, like parentheses or brackets, but don't quote the whole query:

`$ mu find flag:unread AND NOT \( maildir:/Trash OR "maildir:/[Gmail].Trash" \)`